# prenex normal form with two same variables

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How would I put the following statement into prenex normal form?

$∀x P(x) ∨ ∀x Q(x)$

Initially I thought you can use subsumption to do it as follows:

$∀x( P(x) ∨ Q(x))$ but I'm under the impression this is "illegal" because x is not free from the forall quantifier..

Comment: $(\forall x P(x)) \lor (\forall x Q(x))$ is equivilant to $\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$. Because it is quantified the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "quantified the same"?

Comment: Sorry it appears that my above comment is completely false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall x P(x) \vee \forall x Q(x)$ is not equivalent with $\forall x(P(x)\vee Q(x))$. To see this just think of the case $P(x)$ = "x is even" and $Q(x)$ = "x is odd". then certainly (among positive integers) $\forall x(P(x)\vee Q(x))$ hold but $\forall x P(x) \vee \forall x Q(x)$ do not hold.

Instead rewrite $\forall x P(x) \vee \forall x Q(x)$ as $\forall x P(x) \vee \forall y Q(y)$, and then pull out the quantifier one at a time. Thus:
$\forall x P(x) \vee \forall y Q(y)$ is equivalent with $\forall x (P(x) \vee \forall y Q(y))$ which is equivalent with $\forall x\forall y( P(x) \vee Q(y))$ which is in prenex normal form.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if there is a particular name given to the "rewriting" of the expression with a new variable? Just so I can read up a little more on it.

Comment: @cp101020304 I don't think there is a different name for it, they are just two different statements that are equivalent or tautologies, one written by chance in prefix normal form and the other not.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have a negation in front of all of the quantifiers and still be in PNF?

Comment: @cp101020304 I've not found any name on this, but the method is used almost every time you rewrite into prenex normal form, so you could read up on that.

Comment: I don't know about negation, the way I have seen PNF requires quantification of variables in first order logic, to be first, then boolean or logic connectives. I believe the negation is a logical connective and should be only after the quantified variables. For the case of existential and universal quantification I think the preference is trivial because it simply turns one to the other. Also consider the use of PNF, (arithmetic hierarchy and analytic hiearchy) it essentially is the counting of existential or universal quantifiers and classifications of the complexity of sets.

Comment: I did a bit of research and found that any negations must be part of the literals, not the quantifiers @marshalcraft Page 3 here: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~lila/prenex.pdf

Comment: @cp101020304 rewriting a quantified expression with a new token is called **Alpha Replacement**.  Reordering the statement into PNF (or out of it) involves **Quantifier Distribution**.